# PreferenceActivity listpreference value resets to default on reload

Tags: android, settings, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I am facing two problems in my app.

In my app i am using preferenceActivity that contains simple settings for the app (checkboxpreference and listpreference), i have three activities mainActivity,secondActivity and settingsActivity which is prefrenceActivity, in secondActivity i am showing a form that lets user choose a value from a spinner view , what i want to do is user can select a default value of that spinner from settingsActivity so user dont have to manually select the value of spinner everytime.

Now my first problem is: whenever i reopen my settingsActivity(preferenceActivity) the summery of the listPreference is resets to default it only shows selected value while settingsActivity is open, when i go back to mainActivity and i again open the settingsActivity the summery of listPreferece shows default value(if i open list of values,it shows last selected value checked).

Second problem is: Whenever i close the app and open again the preference value gets destroyed means the secondActivity dosent show user selected default value instead it shows the first value of spinner.

here is my code

settingsActivity:

```
public class settingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
```

{
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

```
ListPreference listpref;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstenceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstenceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    listpref = (ListPreference)findPreference("prefDefaultCurrency");
    listpref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listpref.setSummary(value.toString());
            mainActivity.pref_default_currency_index = listpref.findIndexOfValue(value.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
    CharSequence curenttext = listpref.getEntry();
    mainActivity.pref_default_currency_index = listpref.findIndexOfValue(curenttext.toString());

}
```

pref_default_currency_index is a static int variable declared in mainActivity,
i retrive this variable to set the value of spinner in secondActivity, when user clicks a button to open an alertdialoug that contains spinner.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` no. you can't create acitivities yourself

Comment: I am creating object of my main activity, because the variable pref_default_currency_index is declared in MainActivity so im just creating object of that activity to access that variable to store index of the value of listPreference user selected.

Comment: still. you can't do that. that won't work. (you mention, however, that it is a static variable? your editor should be yelling at you for accessing a static variable this way.)

Comment: so what should i do now?!! any suggestions? if i remove static keyword, my variable becomes null again in other activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to both of my problems.. i was making it too difficult when it as very easy!!

My first problem was to get back the option user selected from listPreference from PreferenceActivity, i realized that preferenceActivity automatically saves information to SharedPrererences so what i have to do is just retrieve that information in onCreate() method and save it in a local variable.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

pref_default_currency_index = Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("prefDefaultCurrency","0"));
```

Second problem was that whenever i open settings activity (preferenceActivity) the summery of listPreference was not showing last chosen value, to solve that problem i just have to set the summery of listPreference in setOnPreferenceChangeListener() method

```
listpref = (ListPreference)findPreference("prefDefaultCurrency");
    listpref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listpref.setSummary(value.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

thats it, it was easy!